# gorm and galera connect

Tags: go, go-gorm, galera

I am using GORM for my golang project with a mariadb bdd, but we are migrating to a galera cluster which seems to be exactly the same with multiples node... I cannot find any information on the connexion string to use ... 
for now it looks like :

```
db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", conf.BDDUSER+":"+conf.BDDPASS+"@tcp("+conf.BDDHOST+":"+BDDPort+")/"+conf.BDDSCHEMA+"?charset=utf8&parseTime=True")
```

but now we need to include all the 3 nodes in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended by the developer of gorm, you should use a load balancer to connect to multiple databases. After you have a load balancer, you can use that as the connection string.

Source: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/1055 , https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/1024

Comment: For MariaDB, this is usually [MaxScale](https://mariadb.com/products/technology/maxscale).

Comment: @John Oss Thanks

Comment: @MichaelHampton I setup galera : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/what-is-mariadb-galera-cluster/